# Entity Framework suggest invalid field name

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, firebird

I have two tables in my DataBase, `BUNTS`, which contains information about pieces of steel

```
CREATE TABLE BUNTS (
    BUNTCODE         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    BUNTNAME         VARCHAR(20),
    BUNTSTEEL        INTEGER,
    ......
);
```

and `POLL_WEIGHT_BUNTS`, which contains information about operations that had been performed on each bunt

```
CREATE TABLE POLL_WEIGHT_BUNTS (
    PWBCODE            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PWBBUNTCODE        INTEGER,
    PWBDEPARTMENTFROM  INTEGER,
    PWBDEPARTMENTTO    INTEGER
    ....
);
```

The relationship is one-to-many. I mapped those tables to models. Everything worked just fine.
Recently I've decided to add a field to table BUNTS which would reference to the last operation that had been performed on bunt:

```
BUNTLASTOPER     INTEGER
```

Now my models look like this:

```
[Table("BUNTS")]
public class Bunt
{
    [Key]
    [Column("BUNTCODE")]
    public int? Code { set; get; }
    [Column("BUNTNAME")]
    public string Name { set; get; }
    [Column("BUNTSTEEL")]
    public int? SteelCode { set; get; }
    [Column("BUNTLASTOPER")]
    public int? LastOperationID { set; get; }
    [ForeignKey("LastOperationID")]
    public BuntOperation LastOperation { set; get; }
    public virtual ICollection<BuntOperation> Operations { set; get; }
}

[Table("POLL_WEIGHT_BUNTS")]
public class BuntOperation
{
    [Key]
    [Column("PWBCODE")]
    public int? Code { set; get; }
    [Column("PWBBUNTCODE")]
    public int? BuntCode { set; get; }
    [ForeignKey("BuntCode")]
    public Bunt Bunt { set; get; }
    [Column("PWBDEPARTMENTFROM")]
    public int? DepartmentFromCode { set; get; }
    .....
}
```

After I've made this, when I try to query Operations like this

```
return _context.Operations;
```

it generates an SQL-statement with new incorrect field Bunt_Code

```
SELECT 
"B"."PWBCODE" AS "PWBCODE", 
"B"."PWBBUNTCODE" AS "PWBBUNTCODE", 
"B"."PWBDEPARTMENTFROM" AS "PWBDEPARTMENTFROM", 
....
"B"."Bunt_Code" AS "Bunt_Code"
FROM   "POLL_WEIGHT_BUNTS" AS "B"
```

I assume that now EF looks for a field that is a foreign key for `BUNTS` table, and cant find it. So it generates `Bunt_Code` field, which is missing in my database. But I already have a property `Bunt` in `BuntOperation` class, which references to `BUNTS` table. What am I missing?

---

UPDATE
seems like this solves my problem

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bunt>().HasOptional(b => b.LastOperation).WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bunt>().HasMany(b => b.Operations).WithRequired(op => op.Bunt);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `[ForeignKey("BuntCode")]` I think maybe you're supposed to do `[ForeignKey("PWBBUNTCODE")]` to reference actual column name of the FK, but I haven't done EF in awhile so might be wrong.

Comment: FWIW, you may want to consider adding an `order` column to `BuntOperation`. This gives you the ability to retrieve these in sequence (and reorder at a later date if necessary), and selecting the last operation becomes simply picking off the last [sorted] entry. (You also won't have to worry about updating `LastOperation` in your UoW.)

Comment: Actually I had added order column, although the table is tree-like, referencing previous operation. But the purpose of 'lastoperation' field is to quickly get information about where and which state a piece of steel is now. 'left join' and thats it, instead of sorting by order and picking top1 record

Comment: please remove your solution from your question and add it as an answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like this solves my problem

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Bunt>().HasOptional(b => b.LastOperation).WithMany();
     modelBuilder.Entity<Bunt>().HasMany(b => b.Operations).WithRequired(op => op.Bunt);
}
```